# IBM BladeCenter E with 3000W step up transformer from 120v to 240v

Tags: ibm, blade-server

OK so Im looking to run a IBM BladeCenter E chassis. It requires 240v at 12amp running 1800w.

I want to know if i can run it off one or two 3000W step up transformers like: [http://www.amazon.com/LiteFuze-convertingbox-3600-Converter-Transformer/dp/B0054R0JD2/ref=pd_cp_e_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0054R0JD2)

Now the problem i have is that i only have 120v and to get 240v i would need to patch into my breaker board (NOT wanting to do.) with a 240v running off a new breaker.

Is there a way to run 240v/12amps/1800w from a 120v line. 
PS: Im in Canada (So you have an idea of the electrical system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in Canada and have done *exactly* what you're trying to do.

Now that being said, we were bringing it to trade shows and only doing it given the infeasibility of getting 208V at a trade show.

Sounds like your BC E has 4 x 1800W power supplies? If you're only running one side (slots 1-6) then you only need PSU 1 and 2 and can manage with a single 3000W transformer (the power supplies are 1+1).

If you're running both sides you'll want a transformer for each side (one for PSU 1-2 and one for PSU 3-4).

A better solution would be a BladeCenter S which can run directly off 120V.

Comment: Thanks mikey. I think I might get 2. I would want to run all 14 blades at one. I will have to see if it would blow my house circuit. What UPS  did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Thats cutting *pretty* close in terms of power i suspect - 120V at 15A ([which is what the NEMA 5-15 plugs is the usual for canadian and british power plugs are rated for)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#NEMA_5-15_.2815.C2.A0A.2F125.C2.A0V_grounded.29) - if you have , and that would result in only about 1800W of power.

Answer (score 0):

A typical (US) house has 240v incoming.  You could find two outlets, hopefully in the same room, on different legs and build up a special cord to derive 240v.